# Transpose SSIS XML Elements from rows to columns in powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, ssis

We have a requirement to pull out the version information for all of our packages per project and cross reference that with the version information in SSISDB. I figured i would extract the .dtproj xml info I need into a table and then do a compare.

As a novice Powershell developer this is as far as I have got. It gives me the exact info I need but the data is per row as it appears in the xml file. I would like the data in a table format as follows

| Name | versionMajor | VersionMinor | VersionBuild |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PackageName1 | 1 | 0 | 5 |
| PackageName2 | 1 | 0 | 21 |

here is the xml snippet

```
<SSIS:PackageMetaData SSIS:Name="SomePackage.dtsx">
              <SSIS:Properties>
                <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="ID">{C55A0E46-B4E5-4CE5-8387-277E0472906F}</SSIS:Property>
                <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="Name">SomePackage</SSIS:Property>
                <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="VersionMajor">1</SSIS:Property>
                <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="VersionMinor">0</SSIS:Property>
                <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="VersionBuild">5</SSIS:Property>
                <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="VersionComments">
                </SSIS:Property>
                <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="VersionGUID">{9A60744B-6F04-41BF-9F0C-A820BBD3FDCA}</SSIS:Property>
                <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="PackageFormatVersion">6</SSIS:Property>
                <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="Description">
                </SSIS:Property>
                <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="ProtectionLevel">0</SSIS:Property>
              </SSIS:Properties>
```

this is my code

```
$namespace = @{SSIS = "www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/SSIS"}
$packageXpath = "//SSIS:PackageMetaData//SSIS:Property"
$packageNodes = Select-Xml -Path $path -XPath $packageXpath -Namespace $namespace | ForEach-Object{$_.Node} 
$packageNodes | Format-Table
```

[image]

Looking for the easiest way to do this. I have seen examples using regular expressions to transpose the data from a file and also examples where the element names (not the attributes) are the columns I need using @{Label}.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here, try this:

```
[xml]$xml=@'
<PackageMetaData>
    <Properties>
        <Property Name="ID">{C55A0E46-B4E5-4CE5-8387-277E0472906F}</Property>
        <Property Name="Name">SomePackage</Property>
        <Property Name="VersionMajor">1</Property>
        <Property Name="VersionMinor">0</Property>
        <Property Name="VersionBuild">5</Property>
        <Property Name="VersionComments"></Property>
        <Property Name="VersionGUID">{9A60744B-6F04-41BF-9F0C-A820BBD3FDCA}</Property>
        <Property Name="PackageFormatVersion">6</Property>
        <Property Name="Description"></Property>
        <Property Name="ProtectionLevel">0</Property>
    </Properties>
</PackageMetaData>
'@

$props=$xml.PackageMetaData.Properties.Property

$hash=@{}

$props|%{
    $hash.Add($_.Name,$_.'#text')
}

[pscustomobject]$hash
```

Output should look like this:

[image]

Which is perfect for exporting to CSV / Xlsx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

1. your XML indeed has the namespace declaration `xmlns:SSIS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/SSIS"`
2. it can have multiple `SSIS:PackageMetaData` elements

you could use below code to loop through and output what you want from it.
I'm using a Here-String for the xml content, but in real life you would read it from a file using

```
$xml = New-Object System.XML.XMLDocument
$xml.Load("full path of the XML file")
```

```
[xml]$xml = @'
<SSIS:Packages xmlns:SSIS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/SSIS">
    <SSIS:PackageMetaData SSIS:Name="SomePackage.dtsx">
        <SSIS:Properties>
            <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="ID">{C55A0E46-B4E5-4CE5-8387-277E0472906F}</SSIS:Property>
            <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="Name">SomePackage</SSIS:Property>
            <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="VersionMajor">1</SSIS:Property>
            <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="VersionMinor">0</SSIS:Property>
            <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="VersionBuild">5</SSIS:Property>
            <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="VersionComments"></SSIS:Property>
            <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="VersionGUID">{9A60744B-6F04-41BF-9F0C-A820BBD3FDCA}</SSIS:Property>
            <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="PackageFormatVersion">6</SSIS:Property>
            <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="Description"></SSIS:Property>
            <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="ProtectionLevel">0</SSIS:Property>
        </SSIS:Properties>
    </SSIS:PackageMetaData>
    <SSIS:PackageMetaData SSIS:Name="SomeOtherPackage.dtsx">
        <SSIS:Properties>
            <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="ID">{1234ABCD0E46-777-888-999-AAAABBBBCCCC}</SSIS:Property>
            <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="Name">SomeOtherPackage</SSIS:Property>
            <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="VersionMajor">1</SSIS:Property>
            <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="VersionMinor">0</SSIS:Property>
            <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="VersionBuild">21</SSIS:Property>
            <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="VersionComments"></SSIS:Property>
            <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="VersionGUID">{9A60744B-6F04-41BF-9F0C-A820BBD3FDCA}</SSIS:Property>
            <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="PackageFormatVersion">6</SSIS:Property>
            <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="Description"></SSIS:Property>
            <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="ProtectionLevel">0</SSIS:Property>
        </SSIS:Properties>
    </SSIS:PackageMetaData>
</SSIS:Packages>
'@

$result = $xml.Packages.PackageMetaData| ForEach-Object {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        Name         = ($_.Properties.Property | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'Name' }).'#text'
        VersionMajor = ($_.Properties.Property | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'VersionMajor' }).'#text'
        VersionMinor = ($_.Properties.Property | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'VersionMinor' }).'#text'
        VersionBuild = ($_.Properties.Property | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'VersionBuild' }).'#text'
    }
}

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table

# output to Csv file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'path to the result.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output on screen:

```
Name             VersionMajor VersionMinor VersionBuild
----             ------------ ------------ ------------
SomePackage      1            0            5           
SomeOtherPackage 1            0            21
```

Comment: Hi Theo, your assumptions are correct. The issue is that the code I have above returns XMLElement Types so I am not working with an XMLDocument. I have tried creating a new XMLDocument, adding a root node and then adding the XMLElements to the document but when i run the code it says that my Element isnt in the same context.